# sp_blitzfirst not showing memory grant columns

Tags: sp-blitzfirst

I saw several videos where the know procedure sp_blitzfirst shows the memory grant columns, I even saw it working like that, but on the latest version of the first responder kit, it doesn't show those columns, were those removed?

When I execute it with @expertmode=1 it just show on the messages tab:

```
Setting up configuration variables 
Now starting diagnostic analysis 
Capturing first pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats 
Beginning investigatory queries 
Finished running investigatory queries 
Waiting to match @Seconds parameter 
Capturing second pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats 
Analyzing changes between first and second passes of DMVs 
Analysis finished, outputting results
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps need to use `sp_BlitzCache` instead?

In the source code for sp_BlitzFirst is the line:

> `Run sp_BlitzCache @SortOrder = 'memory grant'` to find queries with huge memory grants and tune them.

On July 14, 2016, the following changes were made (commit [62b6e9df](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/commit/62b6e9dff809540a4291e7aaa7a2cc966f57dae9)):

> Put all of the what’s running now work inside an IF statement so it
>   only runs if we’re in ExpertMode (to minimize executions, since this
>   proc needs to go fast under load.) Cleaned up some of the “memory not
>   granted” and “memory already granted” stuff to just be N/A since it can
>   mean different things depending on whether the query needs memory.

Comment: Thanks Randolph, yes I see that sp_blitzcache does have that information. But my question was related to the fact that sp_blitzfirst used to print that column and now it seems to be missing.

Comment: See updated answer.